# Android Studio 3.5 Execution failed for task ':android:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: android, gradle

When i generate APK, shown message errors while building apk with detail message below:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android:mergeReleaseResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

my build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties: gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

try to (Build->Clean Project) then try again and see if the problem persists

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, the problem is still the same